# Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, материалы, которые помогут разобраться в асинхронности

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, материалы, которые помогут разобраться в асинхронности...

Comment: Что может быть непонятного в асинхронности в js?

Comment: как она работает?

Comment: дважды прочитать классический топик https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: См. также https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот, например, пара ссылок:

[Всё, что нужно знать об async/await. Циклы, контроль потоков, ограничения](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%CC%88-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1-async-await-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-76dde2cb6949)

[Разбираем Async/Await в JavaScript на примерах](https://habr.com/ru/company/skillbox/blog/458950/)